# Running ubuntu only from USB drive

Tags: 12.10, usb

Is it possible to run Ubuntu from the USB-drive only, without getting all changes wiped at restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The changes are saved on a  persistence file which needs to be created when making the diskimage. If you're making the flash-drive image from windows, I presume you're using Universal-USB-Installer, set the persistent file size according to your requirements.[image: universal-usb-installer]

Or if you're doing this from some linux distro, you're probably using Unetbootin. In that case, change the persistent space value as per your needs.
                   [image: unetbootin]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find your answer here in great detail:
 [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)
Just scroll down to the best answer choose by the user explaining how to use "testdrive".